# Merging many variables into one binary variable

Tags: if-statement, dplyr, mutate

I'm trying to create a disabled variable from census data. IPUMS has many different variables for disability (DIFFCARE, DIFFMOB, DIFFEYE, DIFFREM, DIFFPHYS, DIFFMOB, DIFFCARE, DISABWRK, and DIFFANY, DIFFHEAR) they are all coded with 1= No, and 2= Yes.

I'm attempting to create a new variable by selecting all the disability variables listed above that are coded with a "2" (Yes) and creating one master "DISABLED" variable that encompasses individuals that selected yes in at least one of the above categories.

I created a new data frame below. However, I must create a new variable within my existing dataset with all my other variables. I thought I could maybe use "ifelse" but have not figured out how to do it.

```
DISABLED <- bias %>% 
  select(DIFFCARE, DIFFMOB,DIFFEYE,DIFFREM,DIFFPHYS,DIFFMOB, DIFFCARE, DISABWRK, DIFFANY, DIFFHEAR) %>% 
  mutate(DISABLED, "DIFFCARE" ==2 |"DIFFMOB" == 2 |"DIFFEYE" ==2 |"DIFFREM" ==2 |"DIFFPHYS" ==2 |"DIFFMOB" ==2 |"DIFFCARE" ==2 | "DIFFANY" == 2| "DIFFHEAR" == 2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for reading and for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close. Since you did not share your data, I added a small example. Remember that when using functions in the `tidyverse` you should call the names of the columns without quotations. Additionally, the `mutate` should include an `ifelse` to set a particular value if any of the given conditions is met (2) and another value if it is not (1).

```
library(tidyverse)

bias <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
               DIFFCARE = c(1,2,1,1,1),
               DIFFMOB = c(2,1,1,1,2),
               DIFFEYE = c(1,1,2,1,2))

bias |>
  select(DIFFCARE,DIFFMOB,DIFFEYE) |> 
  mutate(DISABLED = ifelse(DIFFCARE ==2 |DIFFMOB == 2 |DIFFEYE ==2, 2, 1))

# A tibble: 5 × 4
#  DIFFCARE DIFFMOB DIFFEYE DISABLED
#     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#1        1       2       1        2
#2        2       1       1        2
#3        1       1       2        2
#4        1       1       1        1
#5        1       2       2        2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I created a new tibble with this with the new variable. I legitimately have spent hours on this, I truly appreciate your time. One last question, the new variable "disabled" does not seem to be recognized. How am I able to attach it to my "bias" data set? Thank you again!

Comment: You can substitute `bias` with the previous lines like: `bias <- bias |> select(...) |> mutate(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your criteria well:

- You want all columns except the first one (id's) so we can easily subset using `bias[-1]`
- You only have values 1 and 2 in your data
- You are only interested if all values are 1 or one or more values are 2 in a row. If you take the max value per row, you satisfy that criteria.

The solution to calculate the values of `DISABLED` can be as simple as this:

```
apply(bias[-1], 1, max)
# [1] 2 2 2 1 2
```

So using `dplyr` your desired output can be achieved using the code below:

```
bias[-1] %>%
  mutate(DISABLED = apply(., 1, max))
```

Results

```
  DIFFCARE DIFFMOB DIFFEYE DISABLED
1        1       2       1        2
2        2       1       1        2
3        1       1       2        2
4        1       1       1        1
5        1       2       2        2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate your time.